# Apache 2.4 method not allowed

Tags: php, apache, methods, http-method

How can i enable DELETE method on Apache2.4 debian(jessie)?

I have tried several solutions, like enable mod_allowmethods, but nothing seems to works.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure it's Apache and not your application that's throwing that error? Also, check that you don't have any `<Limit>`-directive in your Apache config or in some htaccess that blocks the DELETE method.

Comment: i don't think so because the application, developed on symfony php/javascript works very well in dev environment with symfony server:start, but when i switch in prod environment with apache2 everything works fine with GET and POST, but with DELETE i get the error message Method Not Allowed.

Comment: no .htacces and no limit directive in my conf files...

Comment: I've never encountered DELETE being blocked from any Apache server for PHP, unless it was explicitly configured to do so.

Comment: me too :) but now i have to solve this problem... any suggest  for some hidden file to check on debian configuration?